# auto save a notebook using init.m

Tags: front-end, notebooks, initialization, save

I tried to make mathematica autosave as default, so I put Sjoerd C. de Vries's code 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193804/automatically-saving-notebook-or-other-type-files-in-mathematica-files/7197175#7197175
into init.m. However, any notebook will only save itself if I specify a number smaller than 60, and it seems whatever number I choose, it will only save within the first minute, then stopped doing anything.

I am quite confused here. Hope some can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you modify those notebooks after they've been saved?

Comment: Yeah, but after a while, new modification is not autosaved...